# Redirect NULL or blank values from Flat File

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I am importing records from a flat file source to a SQL table which has 4 columns which do not accept NULL values. And what I would like to do is redirect the records which contain a NULL or blank value for the particular 4 fields to a flat file destination.

Below you can see the table configuration:

[image: Table Structure]

And here is a sample from my flat file source where I have blanked out the county_code in the first record, the UCN in the second record, and the action_id in the third.

[image]

If I run my package as it is currently configured, it errors out due to the constraints:

```
The column status returned was: "The value violated the integrity constraints for the column.".
```

So my question is how to I redirect these rows? I think I should do a conditional split, but I am not certain and further I don't know how I would configure that as well.  My attempts have been futile so far.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Derived Column Transformation after your Flat File Source. There you'll test whether the not nullable columns are null.

For ease of debugging, I would add a flag for each of those columns in question.

null_timestamp `(ISNULL(timestamp) || LEN(RTRIM(timestamp)) == 0) ? true : false`

An expression like this will determine whether the column from flat file is null or whether the trimmed length is zero.

Once you have your flags tested, then you'd add in a Conditional Split. The conditional split routes rows based on a boolean expression. I would add a Bad Data output to it and use an expression like

```
null_timestamp || null_country_code || null_etc
```

Because they are boolean, if we OR the values together if any of those were to be true, then the whole expression becomes true and rows are routed to the bad data path.

Comment: Thanks @billinkc - that solution worked nicely after a small modification to the LEN function to cast the datetime column as text.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply add a conditional split and name the Output accordingly:

[image]

Comment: I do like this approach - but how would you expression the condition for datetime and int? I cannot seem to get that expression to evaluate to true.

Comment: Should be possible with a simply type cast, such as the following (with a derived column of the mentioned types): LEN(REPLACENULL((DT_WSTR, 100)[Derived Column 1],"")) == 0

Answer (score 0):

Could you load the data to a temp table first, then using 2 separate queries against the temp table either insert to your table, or write out to flat file?